# Run javascript when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, html

I cant get my javascript to work. It should run when the "user" has scrolled down 2 px but nothing happens. When I remove the Scroll function everything works so have I write something wrong or yeah why is it not working?

**Html**

```
<div id="report"></div>
   <div style="position:relative;">
   <img id="myImage" src="test.svg" style="margin-left:200px; width:100px;" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()  > 2) {
        var animate, left=0, imgObj=null, report = document.getElementById('report'), i=0;
        function init(){
            imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
            imgObj.style.position= 'absolute'; 
            imgObj.style.top = '240px';
            imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
            imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';
            moveRight();
        } 
        function moveRight(){
            left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left, 10);
            if (10 >= left) {
                imgObj.style.left = (left + 5) + 'px';
                imgObj.style.visibility='visible';

                animate = setTimeout(function(){moveRight();},20); // call moveRight in 20msec
                //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,20);
            } else {
                stop();
            }
            //f();
        }       
        function stop(){
            clearTimeout(animate);
        }
        // starting
        window.onload = function() {init();};
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest making a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) out of this. I also wonder if you need to have the functions outside the `(window).scroll` so that the `init()` function can be properly called.  (I also disagree with whoever downvoted. This question can be salvaged easily with feedback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the fiddle, and it works!

http://jsfiddle.net/df6g497p/6/

```
// you forgot the $ <--- this is all i changed 
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

Comment: One of those simple syntax issues that I completely overlooked. Good catch, +1, and thanks for the fiddle. In Chrome, the image goes bonkers, but that seems like what the function itself is supposed to do.

Comment: @JClaspill yes, i sure did not touch the animation routine itself, there could be many suggestions there :D

Comment: Excuse me.. How to make the images to push the content down and not get over?

Comment: @Anton just use `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute` as you can try in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df6g497p/7/)

Comment: @Anton i tested on safari, please specify more what the problem is now, or open a new question